# How to place a photo on this resume template

Tags: xetex

I would like to use this [template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/wilson-resume-cv)(xelatex) for resume, in particular, I want to add a photo in the title block, just in the right of the name, could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix use

```
\title{John Smith -- Résumé \hfill \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}} 
                                                         % Print the main header
```

Replace `\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}` with `\includegraphics[width=<suitable size>]{<yourphotofile}`.

[image]